# Lost horse from bandits killing me

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I too have lost my horse (white) due to an ambush by many bandits that gang up on me and killed me. Once I got back in game I also received this brown horse Tennessee. I looked at the map and that horse was the only horse that had the white saddle icon. I went to the stables to check and i even went to camp where I can receive any of my horses but the best horse that I used is gone. What happened ? Any clue? Maybe the bandits took it and switch off with there’s ?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. It's always worth a search before posting a new question. You can do that with a tag too, for example https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bred-dead-redemption-2%5D+is%3Aq+horse

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it has died. Once a horse is dead... it's dead.